# Sending data from Processing and receiving as uint32_t

Tags: data-type, processing-lang

I need to send data from a processing sketch to an Arduino to pass to a function that takes a uint32_t.  How to I send the data in Processing to be run on the Arduino

Comment: One byte at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend studying up on bitwise shifts (`<<` and `>>`), along with the bitwise OR and AND. They're what you're going to need, especially since `atoi()` would only give you a 16 bit, signed integer.

Let's say that your variable's binary is this (split up into 4 segments):

```
10010010 10110101 01010010 10010100
```

### Sending

```
uint32_t myVarCopy = myVar;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    Serial.write(myVarCopy & 255);
    myVarCopy = myVarCopy >> 8;
}
```

The first line in the loop modifies the variable by bitshifting right eight to allow us to read the data eight bits at a time. We have to, whenever sending data through the serial port, "trim" any data that is in the 9th digit or above using the `& 255` part. This allows us to split this int up into four bytes.

How the `myVarCopy` variable would look over the four iterations:

```
After 1: 00000000 10010010 10110101 01010010 (sent 10010100)
After 2: 00000000 00000000 10010010 10110101 (sent 01010010)
After 3: 00000000 00000000 00000000 10010010 (sent 10110101)
After 4: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 (sent 10010010)
```

### Reading

```
uint32_t buffer = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    buffer = (buffer >> 8) | (Serial.read() << 24);
}
```

This code works by adding the newest data onto the digits 25-32 after it moves everything else over eight bits.

This is how the `buffer` variable would look over the four iterations:

```
After 1: 10010100 00000000 00000000 00000000
After 2: 01010010 10010100 00000000 00000000
After 3: 10110101 01010010 10010100 00000000
After 4: 10010010 10110101 01010010 10010100
```

Depending on how Processing works, you might have to worry about **[little/big endian encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/701644/1512962)** to ensure that your data is in the right order. **Warning:** I haven't tested these yet as an IDE isn't installed on the computer I'm typing this on. Also, I don't know the exact function calls for Processing, so it might not compile.